# Fastest way to reset all the value of a 2-D vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, 2d-vector

How to reset all the values of `vector<vector<int>>` to 0 without using loop and maintaining the size of vector.

Comment: The fastest way is to **do** use a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) in combinations with a `for` loop or `std::for_each`:

```
for (auto &v: vec) {
    std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
}
```

Here [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) will likely fall back to a single call to [`std::memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) (with a decent compiler and optimization flags), but you need the `for` for the 1st dimension.

Since a 2-D `std::vector` is not a single block of memory, there is no way to reset everything to `0` at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) and [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) algorithms:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;

// Iterate over the first dimension of vectors...
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](std::vector<int>& inner_vec)
    {
        // ...fill every inner vector with zeros.
        std::fill(inner_vec.begin(), inner_vec.end(), 0);
    });
```

Note that these algorithms are internally implemented with loops: there's no way to immediately set multiple elements of an `std::vector` at once without iteration.

Comment: Actually, `std::fill` may be (easily) optimized by compilers to not use a `for` loop (for a `std::vector<int>`, gcc 6.2 uses `std::memset` directly).

Comment: @Holt: is it actually implemented as `std::memset` by libstdc++ developers or is the compiler optimizing the `for` loop? I almost certain the compiler is always able to transform the `for` into `memset`-equivalent code in these trivial situations.

Comment: It is the compiler optimizing, but not only the `for` loop inside `std::fill`, also the call to `std::fill`, so the loop body above is basically equivalent to `std::memset(inner_vec.data(), 0, (inner_vec.end() - inner_vec.begin()) * sizeof(int))` (point is that people should not be afraid of `std::fill` for performance issue since it may be optimized in most cases).